# CSS: Responsive Design

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have developed an Office Ribbon for HTML which looks exactely like the Office Ribbon.
Here's a sample screenshot from it:

[image]

But, this is not responsive at all, so my next goal is to make the ribbon responsive.
The screenshot below gives you an idea on how it behaves when it's scaled:

[image]

However, when you look at the office ribbon, you'll notice the following:

[image]

You'll notive that big icons comes small icons with a border around. Labels start to dissapear, legends start to dissapear.

But now I'm reading various things about response design and I see that it's being done by so-called media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

}

This stumbles me because in your CSS you define the width of the page that should be used to apply the style. But in my application, that's not possible because ribbon action items can be placed at runtime. In fact, the goal is to develop a skeleton for the ribbon that does the scaling in some efficient way without knowing what's on the page currently.

So, let's say that when I resize the page and I start hitting the latest ribbon item, this should be made smaller. When I resize further I should go back group, to for example "Delete" and start making the icons smaller there.

I know this question sounds tricky, but I'll hope that there's someone who's willing to help me with this.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle of it ?

Comment: If you want dynamic resizing of items without resizing the page you'll need JavaScript. CSS can only do so much with media queries. If you're then changing the content of the DOM after resizing it makes things a lot more complex. Also, your question is quite vague, can you be more specific maybe with an example?

Comment: This looks more like a recruitment information than a question and even as a question it will be extremely too broad to answer :/.. you may want to narrow it down to a structure example

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a fiddle since it's more a general question on "How to achieve it" rather that solving right now

Comment: Sorry @Spokey it's not requitement at all, I just want to discuss how to achieve something.

Comment: @Novocaine I'm sorry but I don't want to do resizing without resizing the page. I do want to resize the page, but I don't know from which width the items should be aligned differently. It must be something like "If the items does not pass on a single page", than apply that css.

Comment: Google "jquery office ribbon" there seem to be a lot of plugins already available.  But if you are going to write it yourself you need to use js to detect the screen width and if it is smaller than your ribbon, resize and restructure the last element in the ribbon to be the icon with dropdown, and do this backwards along the ribbon until it fits the screen

Comment: but you said *"and I start hitting the latest ribbon item, this should be made smaller"* implying you want elements to resize when there is interaction with the DOM. If you only want elements to resize upon changing the browser window width, you can just set multiple breakpoints in your media queries to handle each size.

Comment: @Novocaine Sorry but I think I misspelled the question. By hitting, I mean, when I resize the window and the borders of the window comes near element X, I want to resize the element. Now, you're saying that I should use breakpoints in my media queries but that's not possible since elements are placed in the ribbon at runtime, so the width would be different every time. Does that means that I need JavaScript and a own custom scaling algorithm that defines if the items does not can be placed, make them smaller, then hide element X, then hide element Y, ...

Comment: The basic answer is yes, JS will be needed to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I guess I need to start writing a LOT of JavaScript to achieve what I really want. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Set 100% width for your body

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
 body {
   background: #ccc;
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you fully understand the question.